# Is it possible to list running containers started by other users with Podman?

Tags: containers, podman, rootless

When I run `rootless` containers as a non-root user, I can see them with `podman ps -a` as that user.

However, I don't see those containers when I login as `root` to the system and run `podman ps -a`.

Is there a way for the `root` user to view all containers that are running, no matter which user has started them?

**Note:** I have tried setting the `--root` option to Podman, without success

```
# podman --root ~username/.local/share/containers/storage ps -a
Error: error creating libpod runtime: database libpod temporary files directory (tmpdir) "/run/user/1000/libpod/tmp" does not match our libpod temporary files directory (tmpdir) "/var/run/libpod": database configuration mismatch
```

Comment: If you're `root`, you could run `sudo -u username podman ps -a`.

Comment: This is the best option so far, thank you.  
Any idea if it's possible for 'root' to view all running containers on the system, regardless of who started them?

Comment: I noticed it works better with 
`sudo -i -u username podman ps -a`
as I received a permission denied when I ran it the other way (from /root home directory)